# How to access certain elements in C++ (in vector)

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and am trying to create a program that asks the user personal questions.

```
std::vector<std::string> name, age, favsinger;
std::cout << "Hello, what is your Name Age Favorite_Singer? ";
std::cin << name;
std::cin << age;
std::cin << favsinger;

int n;
std::cout << "How many siblings do you have? ";
std::cin << n;

for (int a=0;a<n;a++){
    std::cout << "Please enter Name Age Favorite_Singer for sibling #" << a << ": ";
    std::string a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cin >> c; //this part throws me off because favorite singer has a first_name SPACE last_name
    name.push_back(a);
    age.push_back(b);
    favsinger.push_back(c);

}
```

Let's say that the user inputted "3" siblings with the information:

```
Michael 24 Madonna
Sam 20 Michael Jackson
Anna 18 None
```

i want to be able to access each of the sibling's preferences, whether it be their name, age, or favorite singer.

I tried doing

```
age[1]
```

but if i do

```
favsinger[1]
```

it gets thrown off because of the space.

Comment: You may want to use `std::getline` to get a line of input, and interpret that line for your own.

Comment: But if I use std::getline, I'm not sure how to access favorite_singer and take into account of the white space used.

Comment: the way you access element is fine [age.at(index) is better]. element is not inserted into vectors [check length]. better if you post full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use getline, to get the entire input line as a string:

```
std::string input_line;
std::getline(std::cin, input_line);
```

Now you need to parse the string. That is, you need to look at the characters individually, and based on their values, you break up the string into smaller components and store them where they need to go. Parsing is a complicated subject, and its implementation varies on a case by case basis. The standard library provides some rudimentary parsing functionality, and if you can agree to the following restrictions, you can do this very easily using standard library features:

- name is 1 word
- age is 1 word
- favorite singer is whatever is left on the line

Given these restrictions, we can parse `input_line` thusly:

```
std::istringstream iss(input_line);
std::string name, age, favsinger;
iss >> name >> age;
std::getline(iss, favsinger);
```

If you're not familiar with `istringstream`, it is in the `<sstream>` header. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream

Comment: i tried input_line >> name >> age but it is giving me the error "invalid operands to binary expression" for some reason ?

Comment: @Lalala: Oops. That was supposed to be `iss >> name >> age;` -- fixed.